# Which axiom describe the distance between two variables or more?

Tags: real-analysis

i think operator greater than or less than or equal is not enough,

any advanced thing to describe the difference between two variables

x-y < y-z, y-z < z-a  => x-y < z-a  (can this be proved valid? if not, any others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *transitivity* of the relation $<$ is what is used here. Transitivity ($a<b\land b<c\implies a<c$) is one of the defining properties of an *order relation*. Just plug in $x-y,y-z,z-a$ for $a,b,c$ to get what you want.